# Simple Java web app with tomcat, from localhost to deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku

I'm a complete beginner in java development, coming from rails.

I'm following [this Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat) I've git cloned [this example project](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-embedded-tomcat) to try deployment on heroku.
Now I have different app, a small back-end for an android app which runs on Tomcat. It's really simple but I dont understand how/where to put the files from my back-end to the embedded-tomcat app (it's Heroku's example) and push it to Heroku.
My back-end (named ***hatalink***) has this form (and it's inside webapps folder in Tomcat)

```
.
hatalink
└─── WEB-INF
       |
       └─── lib
       |      └───  mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
       |    
       └─── classes
              └─── hatalink
              |      └─── All my classes in *.class
              |
              └─── All my classes in *.java form
              └─── web.xml
```

And the content of my web.xml is all like:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hatalink.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
.... (The same for all classes...)
</web-app>
```

This works fine on my localhost with tomcat, but how do I add the files that are already working from my back-end project to the example project?
Then again am I going right about this? Is there a simpler way/place to deploy this app? Its really simple, I just want it online.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? If it works with a local Tomcat... what exactly isn't working? What happens when you deploy what you've got?

Comment: I cannot understand where to put my java files, my class files and my web.xml in the heroku project so I can push it and start running.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **simpler way** since servlets 3.0.
Instead using **Deployment Descriptor** (web.xml) like you did

```
 <web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hatalink.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
.... (The same for all classes...)
</web-app>
```

**You can use annotations.**

```
@WebServlet(name = "myServlet", urlPatterns = { "/path/to/my/servlet" })
public class YourServletName extends HttpServlet {
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where do I add those lines of code and where do i put my *.java and my *.class files in the Heroku example?

Comment: In this example HelloServlet have annotations. One reason to not running is having both annotations and <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> tags in web.xml. I am using different application server (WildFly) and can't tell you about app structure but you can [look here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your `web.xml` file *always* has to go into `WEB-INF/web.xml` regardless of what kind of server/service you are using. This would have to be the case for your local Tomcat, too.

Your ASCII art picture shows you hev it in `WEB-INF/classes/web.xml`, so you'll need to move it.

You never need to package `.java` files with a web application. I would recommend that you don't include them for a number of reasons.